# ./a.out is not recognized in window for executing lex

Tags: c, windows, lex, dev-c++

Im using DevCpp and flex on windows 10. To execute my lex program i have tried with ./a.out but i got the following error.

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>flex id1.l
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>gcc lex.yy.c
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>./a.out
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

What might be the problem here and please me help me in this.

Comment: At least the `/` on windows needs to be a `\\`.

Comment: Ok... again. Does this `a` executable exist on your desktop?

Comment: No, / is a perfectly valid path component separator on Windows, ever since DOS 3 or so.

Comment: @R.. .. well, just if quoted, like `dir "./"`.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a file name `a.exe`

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>flex id1.l

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>gcc lex.yy.c

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>a

asd ase 12 4rf
  12 4
```

this is how we can execute lex in windows

Comment: Better: use an explicit -o to name the output program rather than relying on a default one.

Comment: "*It creates a file name `a`*" `a.exe` in fact.